# Why do I get underexposure with a Nikon D5200 and freelensed 18-55 kit lens?

Tags: nikon, exposure, freelensing

I own a Nikon D5200 and I use the 18-55 kit lens. I always use the Manual Mode.
I was recently messing around with my camera. I was trying to take photos of a lit lamp in darkness.

As part of the experiment, I clicked photos with the lens held in front of the shutter (removed from the body of the camera) to give the photos a slightly macro-like look.

Now, all the images in Manual mode are underexposed. :(

1. Why?
2. How do I reset?!

Comment: images clicked in auto mode are fine or same as manual underexposed ?

Comment: Images clicked in Auto mode look normal. They're not underexposed.

Comment: good, check the exposure setting (exposure compensation) in you camera. See if it is in negative

Comment: It is when I'm in manual mode. Why?

Comment: that's the reason your pics are underexposed. make it to 0.

Comment: How? By meddling with shutter speed & aperture? But, the images produced are underexposed until I use extremely low shutter speed & f number(When the exposure compensation is at 0). These were settings that I used to use in the dark.

Comment: if you are using default d5200 camera theme then there will be a square shaped icon (with +/- in it) at the right bottom corner. Check if it's value is in positive or negative. If it is negative make it 0 (press i button and navigate to exposure compensation) use dial (up/down) to change the value.

Comment: Doesn't seem to help. Even when my exposure compensation sis +5.0(Max in mine) it is no different.

Comment: plz upload a pic and it's exif

Comment: Do images in manual mode _at the same settings_ appear underexposed? Sorry if this seems basic, but do you understand how to get correct exposure in manual mode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting black photos when I use the Manual feature on my DSLR?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/31014/why-am-i-getting-black-photos-when-i-use-the-manual-feature-on-my-dslr)

Comment: <bangs head on desk>

Answer (score 1):

When Nikon lenses are disconnected from the camera body, the aperture automatically closes down to its smallest size. Unless you manually move the lens's aperture lever wider open and "jam" it at that position using gum, sticky tape, a toothpick stuck in the aperture lever slot, etc., you will always be freelensing at your lens's smallest aperture (f/22 – f/38, depending on your zoom focal length).

For instance, if you were trying to free-lens at f/4 at 55mm, you were 6.5 stops underexposed from what you thought you were using. Even at the +5 exposure compensation, you were still 1.5 stops underexposed.

Thus your only exposure controls in camera when freelensing are shutter speed and ISO.

Comment: that is good info but i do not see an answer to the question. If i understand the question, the camera is now not functioning properly in manual with the lens attached. "why and how do i reset"

Comment: @Alaskaman I guess I misunderstood the question. I thought OP was referring to underexposure *while freelensing*.